# Unbuntu 16 does not have sshd_config

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

I have an `Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS` where I get the following response upon `dpkg-query`:

```
dpkg-query -l 'openssh*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                       Version                    Architecture               Description
+++-==========================================-==========================-==========================-==========================================================================================
ii  openssh-client                             1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10        amd64                      secure shell (SSH) client, for secure access to remote machines
ii  openssh-server                             1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10        amd64                      secure shell (SSH) server, for secure access from remote machines
ii  openssh-sftp-server                        1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.10        amd64                      secure shell (SSH) sftp server module, for SFTP access from remote machines
```

Looks like I do have `openssh-server` installed but I still don't see `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Does `Ubuntu` do things differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file gets installed when you install the `openssh-server` package (it's part of the `postinst` script).

Try running:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server`

Comment: IIRC the postinst script actually copies the file from `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config` (which is the file that the package actually installs) - so another option may be to get a fresh copy from there. See for example [Default sshd_config file for Ubunu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1338866/178692)